# C++ OpenGl GL_LINES renders a triangle

Tags: c++, opengl

Im trying to render in the world axis. But for some reason instead of rendering 3 lines, it renders a triangle. Its ignoring the fact that i have set the renderinMode to GL_LINES. WHy is it rendering a triangle instead of 3 lines? What am i doing wrong?

```
void Axis::render(glm::mat4x4 projectionMatrix, glm::mat4x4 viewMatrix, glm::mat4x4 parentTransform)
{
    glm::mat4x4 worldTransform = transform.M() * parentTransform;
    meshRenderer->bind();

    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("modelMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(worldTransform));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("viewMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(viewMatrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(meshRenderer->getShader()->getUniform("projectionMatrix"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projectionMatrix));
    meshRenderer->render();
    meshRenderer->unbind();
}

void Axis::init()
{
    axisVerts = new GLfloat[18]{
        0.f,0.f,0.f,
        1.f,0.f,0.f,

        0.f,0.f,0.f,
        0.f,1.f,0.f,

        0.f,0.f,0.f,
        0.f,0.f,1.f
    };

    axisColors = new GLfloat[18]{
        1.f,0.f,0.f,
        1.f,0.f,0.f,

        0.f,1.f,0.f,
        0.f,1.f,0.f,

        0.f,0.f,1.f,
        0.f,0.f,1.f
    };


    axisIndices = new GLuint[6] {
        0,1,
        2,3,
        4,5
    };

    Mesh* mesh = new Mesh(axisVerts, axisColors, axisIndices, 18, 18, 6);
    meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, shaderProgram);
    meshRenderer->setRenderMode(GL_LINES);
}

void MeshRenderer::init()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getVertexBufferId());
    GLuint posId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("VertexPosition");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posId);

    if (mesh->hasNormals()) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getNormalBufferId());
        GLuint normId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("VertexNormal");
        glVertexAttribPointer(normId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(normId);
    }

    if (mesh->hasColors()) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getColorBufferId());
        GLuint colorId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("VertexColor");
        glVertexAttribPointer(colorId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorId);
    }

    if (mesh->hasUVs()) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getUVBufferId());
        GLuint uvId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("VertexUV");
        glVertexAttribPointer(uvId, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvId);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getIndexBufferId());

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void MeshRenderer::render()
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    mesh->render(renderMode);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

Mesh::Mesh(GLfloat* vertices, GLfloat* colors, GLuint* indices, int vertexCount, int colorCount, int indicesCount)
{
    verticesCount = vertexCount;
    this->vertices = new GLfloat[verticesCount];
    std::copy(vertices, vertices + verticesCount, this->vertices);

    this->colorCount = colorCount;
    this->colors = new GLfloat[colorCount];
    std::copy(colors, colors + colorCount, this->colors);

    this->indicesCount = indicesCount;
    this->indices = new GLuint[indicesCount];
    std::copy(indices, indices + indicesCount, this->indices);

    normals = nullptr;
    UVs = nullptr;

    init();
}

inline void Mesh::bind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesCount * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    if (normals != nullptr) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalCount * sizeof(GLfloat), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    if (colors != nullptr) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorCount * sizeof(GLfloat), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    if (UVs != nullptr) {
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvCount * sizeof(GLfloat), UVs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesCount * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void Mesh::freeArrays()
{
    if (vertices != NULL) {
        delete[] vertices;
        vertices = NULL;
    }
    if (colors != NULL) {
        delete[] colors;
        colors = NULL;
    }
    if (indices != NULL) {
        delete[] indices;
        indices = NULL;
    }
    if (normals != NULL) {
        delete[] normals;
        normals = NULL;
    }
    if (UVs != NULL) {
        delete[] UVs;
        UVs = NULL;
    }
}

void Mesh::init()
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &nbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &uvbo);
    bind();
    freeArrays();
}

void Mesh::render(GLenum renderMode)
{
    glDrawElements(renderMode, indicesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

And the shaders im using

```
#version 140 core

in vec3 VertexPosition;
in vec3 VertexColor;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec3 color;

void main() {
    color = VertexColor;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1 );
}


#version 140 core

in vec3 color;
out vec4 LFragment;

void main() { 
    LFragment = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Image of how it looks like. it should be 3 lines in different directions representing the world axis but instead is this triangle.

[image]

Comment: You are missing the header file. The issue is probably uninitialized variables.

Comment: Check the argument of the Mesh::render function and see if it is actually GL_LINES. You might have forgot to set the renderMode variable in the MeshRenderer class.

Comment: Ok found it... its a weird one...  I had `inline void setRenderMode(GLenum) { this->renderMode = renderMode; }` So why no errors? so i fixed it to `inline void setRenderMode(GLenum newRendermode) { this->renderMode = newRendermode; }` and now its working.

Comment: @MarkoTaht "why no errors" -- because that's a valid C++ code. Mind you, valid code isn't necessarily correct.

Comment: @YakovGalka i didnt know you can do that in C++. I learned something new. It just seems like a broken code to me.